# the best way to build heat map & table with multiple raws/columns - python

Tags: python, streamlit

what is the best way to build heat map with multiple raws/columns just like on picture (in Python, streamlit).

With plotly is not possible.
any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My original idea was to suggest you use a dataframe styler, because Streamlit accepts it. More on table visualizations [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'stage':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                'Band':['Band1', 'Band2', 'Band3', 'Band4', 'Band1', 'Band2', 'Band3', 'Band4', 'Band5', 'Band6', 'Band7', 'Band8', 'Band5', 'Band6', 'Band7', 'Band8'], 
                'Time':['11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00'], 
                'Guest':[150, 300, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 4000, 8000, 100, 150, 200, 400, 1000, 1200, 1200, 1800]})

def color_hide_nan(val):
    if val < 1:
        color = 'transparent'
    elif 2<val<4000:
        color = 'dimgray'
    else:
        color = "white"
    return 'color: %s' % color


df1=df.pivot_table(index=['stage', "Band"], columns='Time',
                    aggfunc={'Guest':sum}, fill_value=0)
df1.columns=df1.columns.droplevel(0)

df1.astype(int).style.background_gradient(axis=None, cmap="YlGnBu").applymap(color_hide_nan)
```

[image: heatmap in jupiter notebook]

Unfortunately in streamlit - I lost the first level of grouping...
but maybe there are some hacks to restore initial format.

[image: heatmap in streamlit]